# Process Memory Viewing Tool

Tags: memory, process, struct

I'm trying to remember a couple of tools that I used several years ago that allowed you to create structs and map certain regions of memory to those structures so you could view the correct data types that you had defined for the structure. You could also go through and set sections of the memory to datatypes as well.

If anyone remembers what those are or know of anything new that matches that description that would be awesome. Thanks! PS this was for Windows at the time.

Comment: was it reclass?

Comment: IDA has the ability to do that